# pq: invalid input syntax for integer: "$1"

Tags: postgresql, go

After I was trying to `INSERT` into a `postgresql` database simple statement from Go app this error was occurred. I've already made type assertions for `int(value)`, but without luck.

Comment: Please insert example code that results in the error you posted. Aim for a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have resolved this problem by removing single quotes from my `INSERT` statement.
`insert into kids (age,user_id) values ($1,$2);`

instead of

`insert into kids (age,user_id) values ('$1','$2');`